# roi value in tooltip d3js area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have d3js based area chart @ http://plnkr.co/edit/4EEe7EyGRRUH4lJXpHhr?p=preview & here http://jsfiddle.net/g30zhvy8/ where former uses datum and latter uses data, both have working code to display tooltip.

```
 svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);
```

Firstly why the tooltip appears to have less zindex than chart's
Secondly how to show the values closest to given one's or interpolated one's in tooltip for a particular point in area chart. similar question been asked at several places.

This tooltip code works for remaining d3js flavored charts such as bar, pie, donut, line, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tooltip has less z index:* Its because you are creating the tooltip first then the path so the path will be in front of tool tip. In svg there is no concept of z-index. So we need to make the path first then later make the tooltip.

To get the tooltip on mouse hover do the following(comments in the snippet below):

```
  svg.append("path")
    .data([data]) //this is equivalent to datum(data) 
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      tooltip.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;//x position of tooltip
      var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;//y position of tooltip
      tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");//placing the tooltip
      var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);//this will give the x for the mouse position on x
      var y0 = y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1]);//this will give the y for the mouse position on y
      tooltip.select("text").text(d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(x0)+ " " +Math.round(y0));//show the text after formatting the date
    });;
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/07nyA24TeguA7MaIC34b?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah it works in a plunker but not as angular directive as queried here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470062/d3js-angular-directive-for-area-chart-using-d3-mouse-event-for-tooltip